# Does the <nav> element have to have a <ul> in it?

Tags: html

On this page http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/, it mentions how to use the `<nav>` tag for semantic reasons.

In every example, it uses the `<ul>` tag, and mentions using it.

Is this required by the HTML 5 specification or is it just recommended by the author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, [it doesn't.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element)

> [**HTML 5.1 Nightly 4.3.4 The nav element**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element)
>
> A nav element doesn't have to contain a list, it can contain other kinds of content as well. In this navigation block, links are provided in prose:

```
<nav>
  <h1>Navigation</h1>
  <p>
    <a href="">...</a>
    <a href="">...</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="">...</a>
    <a href="">...</a>
  </p>
</nav>
```

<sub>*HTML shortened for simplicity and brevity.*</sub>